# Why can't I use a local variable after a SQL query in Node.js?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

I have to select all tags available in the database, so I could use them in my function, but I can't use the variable after I assigned a value to the variable in the callback function of the query, why?

Code which is not working:

```
    let tags = [];
    db.query(
      `select * from tags`,
      (err, results) => {
        tags = results;
      } 
    )
    console.log(tags);
    return;
```

However this works:

```
    let tags = [];
    db.query(
      `select * from tags`,
      (err, results) => {
        tags = results;
        console.log(tags);
      } 
    )
   return;
```

but why? I want to use the variable `tags` after that query again, but somehow the value assigned to it is destroyed after the query. What would I have to change?

Comment: Area of visibility?

Comment: Hey, I don't know what you mean. I have posted the whole code.

Comment: I think the variable is not assigned because a copy is being created. This can be seen in many languages. It may also be due to asynchronous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is asynchronous language, `db.query` is a network call which will be asynchronous, so if you want to use the response of the query it has to be called after the db.query is executed.

In the first case `console.log(tags);` runs before `db.query` is executed
and you are getting `undefined` response.

In the second case `console.log(tags);` runs after `db.query` is executed thats why you are getting the response from the query.

You use this using Promise:

```
async function queryExec() {

    let tags = await promiseQuery(`select * from tags`);
    console.log(tags);
    return tags;
}

function promiseQuery(query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(query, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(results);
        })
    })
}
```

With async/await:

```
async function queryExec() {

    let tags = await db.query(`select * from tags`);
    console.log(tags);
    return tags;
}
```

Comment: And what would be the solution? I can't use await before the query because I get the error that await is only valid for async functions.

Comment: 2nd statement is correct you can use that, you will get a response from callback function

Comment: if you want to use async/await the function should be like `async function queryExec() {`

Comment: but I need the variable ```tags``` after the query. I need to await somehow until the query is finished but how? The await keyword does not work if I try to use it

Comment: @Opat I have updated the answer, you can promise using that and the use async/await

Comment: Hey, could you just help me to write it without separate functions? So to say inline code? Then I will mark you answer, because somehow I tried it with Promises but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Query is an async function, so the value hasnt returned by the time you try to print it.
within the callback function however, you already have the return value you expect.
If you need it to run synchronously you could await the query function, and have the value in hand.

If you set your function be async then you will be able to await the result.
something like:

```
const foo = async () => {
    let tags = [];
    tags =  await db.query(
      `select * from tags`
    );
    console.log(tags);
    return;
}
```